# Vim Wrong Indent When There Is Dash - in Html Tag

Tags: vim, auto-indent

When I have my custom html tag with the dash in it, Vim can't indent it correctly.

```
<my-tag>
<my-sub-tag>
    this is my tag
    </my-sub-tag>
    </my-tag>
```

Also if I remove the dash out, Vim also indents incorrectly.

```
<mytag>
<mysubtag>
this is my tag
</mysubtag>
</mytag>
```

Unless I have standard html tags, then VIM can indent it correctly like below:

```
<h1>
    <p>som text</p>
</h1>
```

So how can I force VIM to indent `<my-tag>` and `<mytag>` correctly like the standard HTML tag?

Thanks

Comment: a google groups post refers to the solution of your problem look at this [github repo](https://github.com/mgiuffrida/vim2/blob/patch-1/runtime/indent/html.vim)

Comment: I added it in my ~/.vim/bundle/indent/html.vim as I'm using Pathogen. It still doesn't work.

Comment: you are using html plugin, that why. i think there should be some better xml plugin, like https://github.com/sukima/xmledit

Comment: Why do you expect HTML indenting to work on something that is not HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested  [html5.vim](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim) plugin and it solves this problem.